# Change cursor on a win32 label

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to change the mouse cursor for only one label. If I use SetClassLong the cursor for all labels is changed, I was told that I should use SetWindowLong as it is stated [here][1] but for some reason the mouse cursor doesn't change.

I am using a simple DialogBox.

**Edit:**

Sorry, if I didn't include my code. It was late and I was tired.
As recommended I will post the answer below.

Comment: please include your code

Comment: You need to handle the `WM_SETCURSOR` message. You can use the `wParam` value to determine when the message is for the label in question.

Comment: You should post that as an answer rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Potter. I somewhat found the [answer for changing the cursor for a win32 label control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257237/reset-cursor-in-wm-setcursor-handler-properly):

1. Do as the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257237/reset-cursor-in-wm-setcursor-handler-properly) says, you will have something like this.

   ```
   case WM_SETCURSOR:
       if((HWND)wParam == GetDlgItem( hWnd, 1014)) {
           SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND)); 
           SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_MSGRESULT, TRUE);
           return TRUE;
       }
   ```
2. In the properties of the control, make sure to set Notify to True.

[image: static text label properties win32 notify property]